# javascript unable to use double to get total sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript below which calculate the sum from the checkbox value but i can't seem to get to output as double value. Currently I left it as 0 as I tested with 0.00 and it also doesn't work

For example: 8.20 + 12.70 = 20.000999999999998

```
 echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</span>
            <span class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</span>
            <span class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' title='{$CD['CDID']}' value='{$CD['CDPrice']}' /></span>
        </div>\n";
```

JS:

```
var sum=0;
$(document).on("click",".chosen",function() {
    var chk=$(this).find("input");
    if(chk.is(':checked')) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(chk.val());
    } else {
        sum = sum - parseInt(chk.val());
    }
    $('#total').val(sum);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you're parsing your values as integers. An integer can't have decimal values. You need to use `parseFloat()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask my script above is currently using external lib. Would it be possible to use function () ?

Comment: What do you mean with `function()`?

Comment: Means it uses function isChecked(checkbox)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean :(